# How to change vertical listview to horizontal in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I know in jQuery Mobile all listview have a default value as vertical list, but I want to show in my application as a horizontal listview. Does someone have a solution or does jQuery Mobile support for this, I tried to add a data-type attribute equal horizontal but it didn't work, maybe it only work for a select in a form.

HTML file:

```
<div>
   <div>
       <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_kategoria">

       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

JSON file:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost/nailsvaraus/app/json/kategoriajson.php",
       method: "get",
       dataType: "json",
       timeout: 5000
   }).done(function(data){
        $("#").html("");

        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var selector = "#ul_kategoria";
            var img = $("<img>");
            img.css("border-radius", "50%");
            $(selector).append("<li>");
            $(selector).append(img.attr("src", data[i].Kategoriakuva));
            $(selector.append("<h2>"));
            $(selector).append(data[i].Kategorianimi + "</h2>");
            $(selector).append("<p>"+ "</p>");

            $(selector).append("</li>");
        }
   }).fail(function(){
       $("#ul_kategoria").html("lista ei voi tehdä");
   });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrong code, img and text should be append with li, then set width li width equal 20% and float left, problem resolved!